# Space explorers and cats?

Tags: story-identification, books

The book is about space travellers who explore different planets and they eventually come to a planet that is pretty much earth. Some of the explorers being to feel uneasy and scared because they start seeing things. They eventually figure out that  they are cats and that they are descendants of the primal cat. I know the book was written some time around the 50s or 60s

Comment: Who are cats, the explorers or the natives?  Bertram Chandler's *The Inheritors* (1972) features explorers who find a planet populated by uplifted cats (who speak English, and that is significant to the plot); but I doubt this is the answer.

Comment: The explorers are descendants of regular cats and have cat like features but they don't realize this until the end of the book